# Where is a CT scan better than an MRI, where is an MRI better than a CT scan, and where is an ultrasound better than the first two?

Tags: mri, medical-imaging, ct-scans, ultrasounds

I've always assumed that a CT scan is better at "hard" objects, while an MRI is better at "soft" objects, but then I heard that CT scans (even without contrast) can be used to diagnose soft body issues. So now I'm kind of confused:

1. Are there things that an MRI (with contrast) can "see better" than a CT (with contrast)?
2. Are there things that a CT (with contrast) can see better than an MRI (with contrast)?
3. And, for that matter, are there places where an ultrasound can see better than an MRI or CT?

Comment: General principles about this are readily available online, so would you mind to search on your own first and tell what have you've found?